# How to plot several graphs in same window in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot several graphs in Matlab so that they will appear next to one another inside the same window (is "figure" the correct term?). How do it achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`subplot()` is the command you are looking for. [Look up here for more details.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`subplot()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html) command.

Answer (score 2):

The subplot command will allow you to split your figure in multiple subfigures. See the subplot help for usage info.

Regards